# Ошибка в css-loader

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема, мне нужно править чужой проект мне дали исходники я установил все зависимости но когда запускаю сервер вылазит вот эта ошибка

```
error  in ./src/containers/AboutPage.vue

Module build failed: ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals?, esModule? }
    at validate (C:\Users\Pavel\Documents\GitHub\site\node_modules\css-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Pavel\Documents\GitHub\site\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:34:28)

 @ ./~/vue-style-loader!./~/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"id":"data-v-240c3754","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/containers/AboutPage.vue 4:14-387 13:3-17:5 14:22-395
 @ ./src/containers/AboutPage.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
```

packege.json выглядит вот так

```
{
  "name": "Havemotion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Havemotion",
  "author": "iVanSh <mail@ivansh.ru>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "detect-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "qs": "^6.8.0",
    "vue": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-progressbar": "^0.7.1",
    "vue-router": "^2.2.0",
    "vuex": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.2.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint": "^3.14.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^11.0.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^2.0.7",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.8.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^19.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
    "function-bind": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.20.0",
    "jest": "^25.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.1",
    "opn": "^4.0.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "ora": "^1.1.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta11",
    "pug-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-loader": "^11.1.4",
    "vue-style-loader": "^2.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.2.4",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.16.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Если нужны какие то файлы все могу прислать.
Помогите пожалуйста, и большое спасибо заранее!

вот webpack.conf

```
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin')

// add hot-reload related code to entry chunks
Object.keys(baseWebpackConfig.entry).forEach(function (name) {
  baseWebpackConfig.entry[name] = ['./build/dev-client'].concat(baseWebpackConfig.entry[name])
})

module.exports = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.dev.cssSourceMap })
  },
  // cheap-module-eval-source-map is faster for development
  devtool: '#cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': config.dev.env
    }),
    // https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware#installation--usage
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true
    }),
    new FriendlyErrorsPlugin()
  ]
})
```

Comment: Текст ошибки ясно указывает на ошибку и ее исправление, но покажи пожалуйста еще конфиг Webpack'а, на всякий случай (может проблема не в лишних свойствах, а в неправильном закрытии скобок... хоть и маловероятно).

Comment: Добавил webpack.dev.conf.js. И подскажи пожалуйста как это исправить я просто совсем слабый, только недавно познакомился с webpack

Comment: Правила импортируются из `./utils`, так что надо разбираться с его содержимым. Задача проста, она в том чтобы убрать свойство `minimize` из объекта конфигурации css-loader (на которое и ругается загрузчик). Вот тут написано, почему это надо сделать: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/745

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Рад был помочь :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
>    - options has an unknown property 'minimize'.

Загрузчик CSS Loader сообщает о том что "не понимает" параметр `minimize`. Этот параметр [не поддерживается загрузчиком начиная с версии 1.0.0](http://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/745).

Поэтому, для устранения такой ошибки - надо просто убрать свойство `minimize` из объекта конфигурации css-loader.

---

В данном случае, конфигурация находится в массиве `rules`, который формируется функцией `utils.styleLoaders` (импортируемой из `./utils`):

**webpack.conf**

```
var utils = require('./utils')
/* ... */
module.exports = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.dev.cssSourceMap })
  },
  /* ... */
})
```